# Are Intel or AMD processors generally regarded as "better" for Linux

Tags: performance, cpu, hardware, x86

Are there any differences between Intel and AMD processors in how Linux runs? Specifically in terms of performance, optimizations, and driver support?

To simplify things, I am just talking about the vanilla mainline kernel.

Answer (score 5):

Neither AMD nor Intel would release a CPU without solid upstream Linux support; the server market is too important and depends on it.

So, no, there's not a general preference for one or the other. In terms of missing drivers, other components are far more problematic.

Answer (score 4):

It's far from trivial unlike Marcus said.

First, ADL/RPL and upcoming MTL CPUs are still poorly supported under Linux because of their heterogeneous architecture.

In Windows the task scheduler can easily determine the foreground task and assign it to any of P cores, in Linux there's no infrastructure for that, so it's easy to imagine a background task consuming many cores and the kernel pushing the foreground task to an idle E core, instead of a slightly occupied P core which will result in a worse performance for the task at hand.

In Linux `taskset` is still available but it's a quite counter-intuitive utility whereas in Windows there's Task Manager where you can easily assign cores, or even Process Lasso which can automate this process and have rules for the system behavior in case the Windows task manager misbehaves. And don't get me started on how poorly the Linux utility is named. Task? Set? It changes CPU cores affinity / assigns cores to the task.

Secondly, AMD CPUs do not yet support setting frequency limits under Linux when using the amd-pstate driver. I don't think that many people need this feature, as it's mainly useful only for benchmarking or limiting power consumption but it's worth mentioning anyways. You can do that using the classic ACPI driver but it has a very limited range of supported frequencies, e.g. for my Ryzen 7 5800X it only offers: 3.8GHz 2.8GHz and 2.2GHz whereas in Windows I can set frequencies from 400 to 5850MHz using 50Hz intervals.

So, strangely such a core component of the system as a CPU is not fully supported under Linux nowadays.